# How to write java pattern question for arrays

Tags: arrays, design-patterns

Someone ask me to write a code in Java to print number of stars for the value of array like bottom up approach 
For example

```
     
      *
  *   *
* *   *
* * * *
* * * *
3 4 2 5
```

3,4,2,5 are values in array 
How can I do it 
Please help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Although the people here are willing to help you but unfortunately they are not employed to do your homework or your assignments. At least some amount of effort needs to be given in order to solve the problem. Hope you edit the question and add the approach you have tried. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code you have written to try and solve this problem. Based on that starting code, myself or someone else on Stack Overflow may be able to point you in the correct direction.